# What is CSS design code for Heading and Description?

Tags: html, css

How can i make the Heading span tag looks like heading to the top right of the image and Description span tag looks like description to the bottom right of the image?

I have tried using position but its so hard coded and i don't think it is an answer. Any idea? Thanks.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    #a{
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #b{
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c5e2da1f5d1be77ee31491432c3b793f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Img" id="i" />
    <span id="a"> Heading </span>
    <span id="b"> Description </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because on SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Could you solve this problem with one of the answers?

Answer (score 3):

Use `position: relative;` to the wrapping `<div>` and `position:absolute;` to those elements inside..

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

span#a {
  position:absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}


span#b {
  position:absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    #a{
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #b{
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c5e2da1f5d1be77ee31491432c3b793f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Img" id="i" />
    <span id="a"> Heading </span>
    <span id="b"> Description </span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You answer is correct, but is there any way can we achieve the same result without using `position`?

Comment: @MohanRavi not as far as I know. What is wrong with using position?

Comment: @MohanRavi Use css float properties.

Answer (score 1):

you can enclose your *heading* and *description* in one `div`(e.g. `description`). and float both `img` and `.description` in left or right(wherever you want).

try this:

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
      img {
        float:left;
      }
      .description {
        float:left;
      }
      #a{
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      #b{
        font-size: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c5e2da1f5d1be77ee31491432c3b793f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Img" id="i" />
      <div class="description">
        <div id="a"> Heading </div>
        <div id="b"> Description </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out markup. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Okay @Rob. Thanks for advice. next time I will improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It's easier

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    #a{
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    #b{
      font-size: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
<tr><td rowspan="2"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c5e2da1f5d1be77ee31491432c3b793f?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="Img" id="i" /></td>
    <td><span id="a"> Heading </span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span id="b"> Description </span></td></tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out markup. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: It arranges his text how he wants it but someone else made it with what he had so its done